# Solve for $x$ the equation $\ln(10x) - x + 1 = 0$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

My friend is kind of stuck with this problem and I can't find a numerical solution. I plotted the graph to see that there are 2 different solutions but I don't know to mathematically find them. Can you suggest me a method at least that I can apply for this equation?

$$\ln(10x) + 1 - x = 0$$

Comment: Did you try the newton method , the bisection method or regula falsi ? What was the problem ?

Comment: Perhaps the most common method is Newton's method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: How far into mathematics are you? Do you know how to take derivatives? Do you know what a differential equation is? Do you know what conditions a functions needs to satisfy to be invertible? These questions need clarification before anyone should attempt to answer your question.

Comment: In case you were using the phrase "numerical solution" to merely mean "numerical value of the solution", do note that in Mathematics, "numerical solution" has a particular meaning in [contrast](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/935458/21813) to "analytical solution": the former uses numerical approximation, whereas the latter uses purely symbolic manipulation.

Comment: Iterating the functions $f(x)=\ln(10x)+1$ and $g(x)=1/(\ln(10/x)+1)$ starting from $x=1$ will converge to the two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln(10x) +1 - x =0$$
$$\ln(10xe^{-x}) = -1$$
$$10xe^{-x} = \frac{1}{e}$$
$$-xe^{-x} = -\frac{1}{10e}$$
Since $-\frac{1}{10e}\in[-\frac{1}{e},0)$, $-\frac{1}{10e}$ is in the domain of both branches of the $W$ function:
$$-x = W_{0}(-\frac{1}{10e}) \text{ or }W_{-1}(-\frac{1}{10e})$$
$$\boxed{x = -W_{0}(-\frac{1}{10e})\text{ or }-W_{-1}(-\frac{1}{10e})}$$